# Error installing earlier librxtx-java version (rxtx-2.2pre2) " bin/javac: No such file or directory "

Tags: java

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

`java -version` gives:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

A program i want to run, it needs rxtx-2.2pre2 version (an earlier librxtx-java version), so i downloaded the **rxtx 2.2pre2 (prerelease)** from http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download and downloaded it in my downloads folder, extracted it there and followed the instructions from http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux , but when i use the command `sudo sh ./configure`, at some point it gives me the error:

```
./configure: line 21838: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/bin/javac: No such file or directory /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241 configure: WARNING: using JAVA_HOME environmental variable adjusted java.home is /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241 checking os.name  Error: Could not find or load main class conftest

checking os.arch  Error: Could not find or load main class conftest

checking java.vendor  Error: Could not find or load main class conftest

checking java.version  Error: Could not find or load main class conftest

checking os.version  5.3.0-42-generic ./configure: line 21808: cd: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/include: No such file or directory ./configure: line 21809: cd: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/include: No such file or directory

WARNING: configure is having a hard time determining which directory contains the file jni_md.h. Edit Makefile and fix the variable JAVANATINC to point to the correct directory.

The following options are available: find: '/usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/include': No such file or directory

If there are more than one option available the first was selected.

configure: creating ./config.status config.status: creating Makefile config.status: creating config.h config.status: executing depfiles commands 
soldy@soldy:~/Downloads/rxtx-2.2pre2$
```

It says /usr/java/jre1.8.0_241/bin/javac: No such file or directory. Indeed, there is no file named "javac" in this directory. the files in this directory are:

```
ControlPanel  javaws    jjs      orbd     policytool  rmiregistry  tnameserv
java          jcontrol  keytool  pack200  rmid        servertool   unpack200
```

Shall i change the code to look for one of the files that really exist in there? and if yes, which one?

Comment: It looks like you have installed only the JRE package - not the JDK package that includes `javac`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to compile this package from source, it is packaged as [`librxtx-java`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rxtx) with version *2.2pre2*.

Just install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java
```

If you really need to compile it - install necessary build-tools with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential default-jdk
software-properties-gtk # to enable Source code
sudo apt-get build-dep librxtx-java
```

and then proceed.

Comment: I see.. i did that before, it gave me an error, i installed it again, since you saw me that link, and when i try to run a program **($sudo avr4l)**, it says:




`
**WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch**
NEXT_LINE:
 **Jar version = RXTX-2.2-20081207 Cloudhopper Build rxtx.cloudhopper.net**
NEXT_LINE:
 **native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2**
`

Is the native lib Version, my version?
Also, how do i see my version of txrx-java?

Comment: I can't understand the original problem from your comment. Please ask it in new question.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded rxtx 2.1-7r2 (stable) from http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download, followed the instruction from the downloaded file, also i needed to add java in the environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649140/make-bin-javac-command-not-found , follow the instructions here: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux and this eeror solved...